# SSRS integration with GitHub

Tags: github, reporting-services

I am an SSRS developer.  I use GitHub for version control.  I take a copy of reports into local repository and push it to GitHub repo manually.  I am looking for options to do it in a better way.  Please, can I get some suggestions?

Comment: Are your reports already in a visual studio report project?

Comment: @aduguid no they are created using Report Builder

Comment: ok, so I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and SSDT for VS2017.  I created new reports using VS2017.  It saves a copy of the .rdl files into my local machine which can be uploaded to Git.  I have not found a solution for the existing reports created using Report Builder tool.  I tried to download all the .rdl files from Report Server using the script given in this link https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SSRS-all-RDL-files-from-00488104 but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that SSRS does have an API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/developer/rest-api?view=sql-server-ver16

And knowing that Microsoft Report Builder can work locally with `.rdl` files, or that you can manually edit them as XML data.

You should be able to setup githooks for using the API on push to replace changes files on your SSRS.